# Improving my retrofitter foundry casual deck

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

I am playing in a casual environment where lord mode or ffa is played, 4+ players.
I had the idea to build a retrofitter foundry deck, because i have the cards at home.
Card selections are: legcy legit cards an no more than 5€/cards (european prices).

The list:
Lands

```
2 Ancient Den
4 Great Furnace
4 Seat of the Synod
6 Island
5 Mountain
1 Plains
```

Total of 22 lands. I tested with more an and less, but I have the feeling this is the right amount for the mana hungry retrofitter foundry.
I have shocks and fetches, but not too sure if I should pay the life where a lot of extort and similar effects are going around without any lifegain.

Creatures:

```
1 Brudiclad, Telchor Engineer
1 Pia and Kiran Nalaar
4 Thopter Engineer
2 Trinket Mage
```

Creatures are either tutors (Trinket mage for land or retrofitter foundry) or payoff cards. Mom and Dad for thopters which grow into 4/4s for tapping the foundry.

Planeswalker

```
2 Saheeli, Sublime Artificer
```

Yeah, because free tokens or copy retrofitter UEOT.

Enchantments

```
2 Ghirapur Aether Grid
3 Intangible Virtue
```

buff my tokens. Synergize with Saheeli

Artifact

```
4 Retrofitter Foundry
1 Unwinding Clock
```

Clock because why not.

Instant

```
4 Lightning Bold
2 Whir of Invention
```

2 Whirs because I often lack the UUU

Sorcery

```
2 Ponder
3 Preordain
2 Role Reversal
4 Thoughtcast
```

I like Role Reversal, because i can change on t3 with a retroffiter T1.

What I am lacking is, some form of good removal. Bold is good, but in FFA it's not always the best option. I am considering Dispatch for bolt, or some go wide wraths like anger of the gods.

Also, if I don't drop retro on t1 i have no good t2 drop. Cantrip into intangible into thopter engineer is nice, but not that good, because i have to chump block a lot on t3 and with the foundry i can block sack.

The meta is mostly vampires with dark rituals, bant spirits, green stompy and some variants, but all more in kept casual playable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll find that it's actually a lot harder to effectively help someone tune a deck for an unknown casual meta than for a known competitive meta. A lot of deck construction depends on what threats and answers are common in the rest of the meta, plus the expected speed of games, the impact of politicking in multiplayer, etc. For example, you mention that you often need to chump block on turn 3, but it's not obvious what creatures you often need to block, or why it's important that they don't get through at that time, and those things can affect how that problem should be addressed.

Comment: Have you tried looking at other competitive decks that use thopters? Sword of the Meek + Thopter Foundry is pretty popular, but some recent cards like Sai, Master Thopterist or Thopter Spy Network could also be starting points.

Comment: So, if i would have added that there can be creatures equiped with sword of feast and famine, which accelerates my opponents too fast? And that there can be some vamps, strong enough to kill my saheeli, would that be enough? Not mentioning that there can be goblin lackeys too, but they come t2.
I had a look at the competetive stuff, but i just don't like the thopter combos personally.